# filter conditoned on multiple columns nested

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to choose rows that two columns of that row satisfies two conditions. And the second condition is nested in the first condition. For example, following codes give me exactly what I want to do

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- data.frame(group1 = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3)),
                  group2 = rep(c(1:3),2),
                  value = 1:6)
df1
selection <- data.frame(G1=c("A","B"),G2=c(2,1))
selection
left_join(selection,df1,by=c("G1"="group1","G2"="group2"))
```

I used `left_join()` function here. I wonder that can I use functions such as `filter()`? Like what we usually do when we choose rows. So this would save me some time to change variable name back.

Comment: This seems preferable to any code you could come up with using `filter` Some torturous `filter((G1 = "A" & G2 = 2) | ...` would work, but would be pretty tiresome to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep column names from `df1`, you can switch `df1` with `selection`, then use `inner_join` or `right_join`:

```
inner_join(df1,selection,by=c("group1"="G1","group2"="G2"))

#  group1 group2 value
#1      A      2     2
#2      B      1     4
```

---

```
right_join(df1,selection,by=c("group1"="G1","group2"="G2"))

#  group1 group2 value
#1      A      2     2
#2      B      1     4
```